# Requirement for weak pullback to be a Lie groupoid (Moerdijk)

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ct.category-theory, lie-groupoids

Let $\phi:\mathcal{G}\rightarrow  \mathcal{K}$ and $\psi:\mathcal{H}\rightarrow \mathcal{K}$ be morphisms of Lie groupoids.

We define weak pullback/2-fibre product corresponding to $\phi:\mathcal{G}\rightarrow \mathcal{K}$ and $\psi:\mathcal{H}\rightarrow \mathcal{K}$ to be a groupoid $\mathcal{G}\times_{\mathcal{K}}\mathcal{H}$ whose object set is 
$$(\mathcal{G}\times_{\mathcal{K}}\mathcal{H})_0=\{(a,\alpha,b)| a\in \mathcal{G}_0, b\in \mathcal{H}_0,\alpha:\phi(a)\rightarrow \psi(b) \in \mathcal{K}_1\}.$$
Given $(a,\alpha,b ),(a',\alpha',b')\in (\mathcal{G}\times_{\mathcal{K}}\mathcal{H})_0$ we declare 
$$\text{Mor}((a,\alpha,b),(a',\alpha,b'))=\{u:a\rightarrow a'\in \mathcal{G}_1, v:b\rightarrow b'\in \mathcal{H}_1| \alpha'\circ \phi(u)=\psi(v)\circ \alpha\}.$$

We then see that $$(\mathcal{G}\times_{\mathcal{K}}\mathcal{H})_0= \mathcal{G}_0\times_{\phi,\mathcal{K}_0,s}\mathcal{K}_1\times_{t\circ pr_2,\mathcal{K}_0,\psi}\mathcal{H}_0$$

$$(\mathcal{G}\times_{\mathcal{K}}\mathcal{H})_1=\mathcal{G}_1\times_{t\circ \phi,\mathcal{K}_0,s}\mathcal{K}_1\times_{t,\mathcal{K}_0,s\circ \psi}\mathcal{H}_1.$$
Source, target maps are given by 
$$s(u,\gamma,v)=(s(u),\gamma\circ \phi(u),s(v))$$
$$t(u,\gamma,v)=(t(u),\psi(v)\circ \gamma, t(v))$$

[Moerdijk](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0203100.pdf)  (in page no $5$)  says that assuming $t\circ pr_2:\mathcal{G}_0\times_{\mathcal{K}_0}\mathcal{K}_1\rightarrow \mathcal{K}_0$  is a submersion confirm that $\mathcal{G}\times_{\mathcal{K}}\mathcal{H}$ is a Lie groupoid. All I can see is  $(\mathcal{G}\times_{\mathcal{K}}\mathcal{H})_0$ and $(\mathcal{G}\times_{\mathcal{K}}\mathcal{H})_1$ are manifolds (being pullbacks under submersions) if $t\circ pr_2:\mathcal{G}_0\times_{\mathcal{K}_0}\mathcal{K}_1\rightarrow \mathcal{K}_0$  is a submersion.

But, what I do not understand is, why does $s,t$ are smooth?

For source map, first and third coordinates are submersions. Second projection $\gamma\circ \phi(u)$ does not seem to be submersion, unless I assume $\phi:\mathcal{G}_1\rightarrow \mathcal{K}_1$ is a submersion. Similarly, to prove target map is submersion, first and third projections are submersions but second projection is $\psi(v)\circ \gamma$ does not seem to be submersion unless I assume $\psi:\mathcal{H}_1\rightarrow \mathcal{K}_1$ is a submersion.

I think we should also assume $\phi:\mathcal{G}_1\rightarrow \mathcal{K}_1$ and $\psi:\mathcal{G}_1\rightarrow \mathcal{K}_1$ are submersions.

Does it follow with out assuming $\phi,\psi$ are submersions?

If $\phi$ is submersion, then, $$\mathcal{G}_1\times_{t\circ \phi,\mathcal{K}_0,s} \mathcal{K}_1\rightarrow \mathcal{K}_1\times_{t,\mathcal{K}_0,s}\mathcal{K}_1$$ given by $(u,\gamma)\mapsto (\phi(u),\gamma)$ is submersion. 
 As multiplication map $\mathcal{K}_1\times_{t,\mathcal{K}_0,s}\mathcal{K}_1\rightarrow \mathcal{K}_1$ is submersion (thanks to David Roberts), the composition map given by 
$$(u,\gamma)\mapsto (\phi(u),\gamma)\mapsto \gamma\circ \phi(u)$$ is submersion.

> So, for $(u,\gamma,v)\mapsto \gamma\circ \phi(u)$ to be submersion, we need $\phi$ to be submersion even after using multiplication map is submersion.

What am I missing here?

Comment: The composition map in a finite-dimensional Lie groupoid is a submersion. I've not seen this anywhere, I had to prove it myself.

Comment: Oh.. Thanks. I will check it :) @DavidRoberts

Comment: @DavidRoberts I see why it is submersion... Given a Lie group $G$ the multiplication map $m:G\times G\rightarrow G$ is a submersion... Same idea for Lie groupoid also.. the multiplication map (composition) is submersion... so source, target maps for groupoid mentioned above are submersions...

Comment: Allow me to consider a special case of this question: is it necessary for $M \to N \leftarrow M'$ to be submersions for $M\times_N M'$ to be a manifold? In fact no, since transversality is a sufficient condition. And, if $M$ is a closed submanifold of $N$, and $M'=M$, then $M\times_N M = M\cap M = M$ is a manifold, and the derivative of both inclusions is *nowhere* surjective.

Comment: @DavidRoberts that’s true. For pullback to be manifold, all we need is intersection is transversal.. Here I am trying to see if $t\circ pr_2: \mathcal{G}_0\times_{\mathcal{K}_0}\mathcal{K}_1\rightarrow \mathcal{K}_0$  being submersion is sufficient to prove $\mathcal{G}\times_{\mathcal{K}}\mathcal{H}$ is a Lie groupoid....

Comment: Well clearly the answer is to your boxed question above is 'no', since I just gave counterexamples. You should draw attention to the actual question you are interested in.

Comment: @DavidRoberts I will edit it.. I am travelling... I will edit it when I get some time..

Answer (score 2):

This answer is too big to fit into a comment, and doesn't *quite* answer the question.

**Lemma** Given a diagram
$$
\array{
U & \to &  V & \leftarrow &W \\
\downarrow && \downarrow  && \downarrow \\
X &  \to & Y & \leftarrow & Z 
}
$$
of finite dimensional manifolds and submersions, then the induced map $U\times_V W \to X\times_Y Z$ is a submersion.

This is proved by taking $(u,w) \in U\times_V W$ and looking at the diagram of tangent spaces and seeing that the induced linear map at $(u,w)$ is surjective.

You can iterate this lemma to deal with the case of maps between limits of longer zig-zags, like $A \to B \leftarrow C \to D \leftarrow E$.

The source and target maps for the groupoid you are looking for are *almost* examples of such maps between pullbacks. What you need is a generalisation of this above lemma that applies in your situation. Do the source map, without loss of generality, the target map then follows immediately. If you pick a point in the arrow space of the pullback, look at the diagram of tangent spaces at all the other points in the image of that point. You will get a diagram of vector spaces, and it should be possible to see why the map you are interested in is then surjective. As this was for a generic point, the source map has surjective derivative everywhere.

Comment: In the diagram, it should be sufficient that the downward arrows are submersions, as well one pair of the horizontal arrows, that is, either both left-pointing or both right-pointing arrows, so that the pullbacks exist.

Comment: I will write down the details and will reply soon. Thank you :)